# Convert vector<string> to vector<double> C++ ERROR

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to convert a vector string to vector double using stod.

So far I have:

```
vector<string> i = {"2.2", "2313.1"};
vector<double> rebuild;

for (int i=0; i<=v.size(); i++) {
        rebuild.push_back(stod(v[i])); ///converts  vector<string> to  vector<double>
    }
```

but I get the error "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stod: no conversion"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop is reading beyond the bounds of the `v` vector:

`for (int i=0; i<=v.size(); i++)`

It should be:

`for (int i=0; i < v.size(); i++)`

Comment: :/ how could I have missed that? Thanks.

Comment: Or if you're using C++11 another option is `for(auto d : v)`